# _GLIBCXX_ABI_TAG_CXX11 error in Qt5 project

Tags: c++11, cmake, qt5

I created a minimal demo which is throwing error messages in a cmake project. It looks like I can not use Qt5 in my C++11 [minimal error demo](https://github.com/dgrat/weird_fail)
The code is error free and compiles on its own. Can someone explain what might be the problem?

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/cstddef:41:0,
                 from /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qglobal.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qnamespace.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qobjectdefs.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qobject.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qabstractanimation.h:37,
                 from /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/QtCore:4,
                 from /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets/QtWidgetsDepends:3,
                 from /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets/QtWidgets:3,
                 from /home/dgrat/weird_fail/src/QSOMReader.h:15,
                 from /home/dgrat/weird_fail/src/weird_fail.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:803:7: error: expected identifier before string constant
       _GLIBCXX_ABI_TAG_CXX11
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:803:7: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before string constant
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:803:7: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
       _GLIBCXX_ABI_TAG_CXX11
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:814:7: error: expected identifier before string constant
       _GLIBCXX_ABI_TAG_CXX11
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:814:7: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before string constant
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:814:7: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
       _GLIBCXX_ABI_TAG_CXX11
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:814:7: error: ‘int std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::__abi_tag__(int)’ cannot be overloaded
       _GLIBCXX_ABI_TAG_CXX11
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:803:7: error: with ‘int std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::__abi_tag__(int)’
       _GLIBCXX_ABI_TAG_CXX11
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:838:7: error: expected identifier before string constant
       _GLIBCXX_ABI_TAG_CXX11
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:838:7: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before string constant
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:838:7: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
       _GLIBCXX_ABI_TAG_CXX11
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:838:7: error: ‘int std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::__abi_tag__(int)’ cannot be overloaded
       _GLIBCXX_ABI_TAG_CXX11
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_tree.h:803:7: error: with ‘int std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>::__abi_tag__(int)’
       _GLIBCXX_ABI_TAG_CXX11
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_map.h:694:7: error: expected identifier before string constant
       _GLIBCXX_ABI_TAG_CXX11
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_map.h:694:7: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before string constant
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_map.h:694:7: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
       _GLIBCXX_ABI_TAG_CXX11
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_multimap.h:599:7: error: expected identifier before string constant
       _GLIBCXX_ABI_TAG_CXX11
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_multimap.h:599:7: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before string constant
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_multimap.h:599:7: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
       _GLIBCXX_ABI_TAG_CXX11
       ^
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <QApplication>
```

to the beginning of `weird_fail.cpp`

Comment: Are you sure that it is before all other includes? It's `#define __attribute` in the `Functions.h` that is wrecking havok. The `Functions.h` should be included last if you really need that file. Or rename the `__attribute` to something like `MY_ATTRIBUTE`.

Comment: It was the macro definition